export stl file doesn't show image plane shrinkwrap
I'm new to blender. I wanted to put different pictures on my object. So what I did was import image as plane. Then shrinkwrap it to 1 surface of the square.

Then I export it as an stl file. The problem is when I view the stl file, the image isn't on it. And yes, I've check all 6 surfaces of the cube.

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Of course there is no image. STL files have no materials, no modifiers, no multiple objects...
